# How to use abstract base class properly C#

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

Hi I'm creating a geometry library in C#...

I have an abstract class shape. 
I have defined a class vector (also representing (x,y) points).

I would like to use a variety of geometrical objects, curves, lines, arcs, paths etc

To do this I've defined an abstract `Segment` class and derived a number of classes e.g. `LineSegment` (see below), `CurveSegment`, `ArcCircleSegment`, `BezierCurveSegment`, `HalfInfiniteLine` etc.

I've also defined a class `Path` (NOT abstract) which is intended to represent a number of segments joined together (like what you might get from a drawing application). In this i include a List member of Segments (`List<Segment>`).

Then i wish to derive classes from `Path`, the key example being `LinePath` which should contain only `LineSegments`. The problem i have is i'd like to be able to call the get property on a `LinePath` object assuming it'll return a `LineSegment`. Is this possible without explicitly casting each time?

I want to avoid making `Path` abstract as i might have a path of multiple Segment types.

```
public class LineSegment : Segment 
{
    private vector m_start;
    private vector m_end;
    private vector m_vector;

    public vector Start
    {
        get { return m_start; }
        set { m_start = value; }
    }

    public vector End
    {
        get { return m_end; }
        set { m_end = value; }
    }

    public vector Vec
    {
        get { return m_vector; }
        set { m_vector = value; }
    }

    public double Length()
    {
        return Vec.length();
    }

    public LineSegment(vector v0, vector v1):base()
    {
        this.Start.x = v0.x;
        this.Start.y = v0.y;
        this.End.x = v1.x;
        this.End.y = v1.y;

        this.Vec = this.End - this.Start;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a thought rather than overloading `Path` to `LinePath` could you instead have `Path<T>` and then create `Path<Segment>` or `Path<LineSegment>` as needed. I've not thought too hard about whether this will work but it seems like it may work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can do something like this:

Make your path class generic

```
public class Path<T> where T : Segment
{
    private IList<T> segments = new List<T>();

    public IList<T> Segments { get { return this.segments; } }
}
```

You can then create your LinePath object

```
public class LinePath : Path<LineSegment>
{
}
```

that way you can ensure that all segments in your `LinePath.Segments` are `LineSegments` while still being able to re-use the `Path` class for any operations which act against a `Segment`.

Comment: But this way you cannot have a Path with different Segment types together.

Comment: You can by creating a non-generic version of path public class Path : Path<Segment> which can then contain any type of Segment.

Comment: Thanks...this seems like a good elegant solution. I must read up a little on generics it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the Path property on your derived classes. LinePath can have:

```
public new List<LineSegment> Segments 
{
    get
    {
        return (List<LineSegment>)base.Segments;
    }
}
```

This way you will enforce the correct type usage.

Comment: You want to avoid defining 'new' method and property signatures as they are not compatible with polymorphism.

Comment: I guess this is a simpler (not using generics) solution?

Comment: @Trevor: I don't get why they are not compatible with polymorphism. Can you develop that a bit more?

Comment: @SoMoS This should explain it easier than I can manage in a comment http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html

Comment: Going down the generic route....about time i learnt how to use them. One thing which isn't 100% clear is why define the member as an Interface List and not just a List (IList<T> instead of List<T>).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a requirement where your base class should provide default implementation of certain methods whereas other methods should be open to being overridden by child classes use abstract classes.

For e.g. again take the example of the Vehicle class above. If we want all classes deriving from Vehicle to implement the Drive() method in a fixed way whereas the other methods can be overridden by child classes. In such a scenario we implement the Vehicle class as an abstract class with an implementation of Drive while leave the other methods / properties as abstract so they could be overridden by child classes.

–> **The purpose of an abstract class is to provide a common definition of a base class that multiple derived classes can share.**

For example a class library may define an abstract class that is used as a parameter to many of its functions and require programmers using that library to provide their own implementation of the class by creating a derived class.

Use an abstract class

```
When creating a class library which will be widely distributed or reused—especially to clients, use an abstract class in preference to an interface; because, it simplifies versioning. This is the practice used by the Microsoft team which developed the Base Class Library. ( COM was designed around interfaces.)

Use an abstract class to define a common base class for a family of types.

Use an abstract class to provide default behavior.

Subclass only a base class in a hierarchy to which the class logically belongs.
```